# find derivative with defined function

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

```
  s[a_, b_] := NDSolve[{y''[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == a, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x,0, b}]
```

I need to find the minimal of $\int _1^by[x]^2$ in the region $-1<a<1$ and $b>1$, and express $a$ in terms of $b$, what I am doing is like:

```
w[a_,b_]:=First[NIntegrate[Evaluate[y[x]^2 /. s[a, b]], {x, 0, b}]]
j[a_,b_]:=D[w[a,b],a]
h[b_]:=a/.FindRoot[j[a,b]==0,{a,0}]
```

I am too naive, does anyone have any idea? thanks 
AS  Michael E2 suggests using ND, so instead of

```
j[a_,b_]:=D[w[a,b],a]
```

I change it as:

```
j[d_,b_]:=ND[w[a,b],{a,1},d]
```

but when I enter j[1,1] as a check, I receive a warning instead of the a number.
So I tried  b.gatessucks's suggestion, using NMinimize,

```
    w[b_]:=NMinimize[NIntegrate[Evaluate[y[x]^2 /. s[a, b]], {x, 0, b}],{a}]
```

Unfortunately, w[1] does not give a number.
Anyway, thanks for your help. and thanks ruebenko

Comment: I think you will probably have to use [`ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html) to find the derivative in `j`.

Comment: Why not using `NMinimize` on w ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. We make it a parametric value. Note that the integration is part of that.

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == a, 
    y'[0] == 1}, Integrate[y[s]^2, {s, 0., b}], {x, 0, b}, {a, b}];
Plot[pf[a, 1.1], {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Then we construct the derivative at a specific `b`:

```
dpf = D[pf[a, 1.1], a];
```

Note that the result is still a parametric function. Next, we need to numericalize the result from the integration as it can not evaluate other wise:

```
j[x_] := N[dpf /. {a -> x}]
```

While finding the minimum `NIntegrate` complains a bit but I think those are OK but you could tune this further.

```
FindRoot[j[a] == 0, {a, -1/2., -1., 1.}]
(* messages *)
(* {a -> -0.532829} *)
```

Comment: thanks very much! I get it. for very b, I find the value of a that minimize the function. I express it as j[b_] := Quiet[FindRoot[N[D[pf[a, b], a] /. {a -> a}] == 0, {a, -0}]]

Comment: @user8583, you could also have the b as a parameter. Something like: `dpf = D[pf[a, b], a];j[x_, y_] := N[dpf /. {a -> x,b -> y}]; FindRoot[j[a, 1.1] == 0, {a, -1/2., -1., 1.}]` should also work.

Comment: I find another problem, `pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == a, 
    y'[0] == 1}, Integrate[y[s]^2, {s, 0., b}], {x, 0, b}, {a, b}];
Plot[pf[a, 1.1], {a, -1, 1}]`, if I define another function,`g[a_,b_]:=c/.FindRoot[a+b==c,{c,0}]`, and put this `g` inside the original function, so the original function becomes `y''[x] == g[a,b] y[x] Cos[x + y[x]]`. But _mathematica_ gives me an error message. Do you have any idea? thanks a lot

Comment: @user8583, this is a new question which you should post.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway